# Text in mobile mode not fixing self

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having text not wanting to fill the whole page but only half of it. I have tried clear both; `width: 100%;` but neither work. Any suggestions?

I am testing this with the iPhone 4 on Chrome emulation. I have to input more characters of non code because of Stack Overflow's weird little error so I am hoping everyone is having good day!

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    color: white;
}

html,body
{
 height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}
#container
{
 min-height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}
#banner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(images/banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#content
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
 padding-bottom: 240px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 10px;
}
#footer
{
 background-color: #333;
 position: relative;
 height: 240px;
 margin-top: -240px;
 clear: both;
}

/* Conditionals */

/* BANNER */
.banner-text
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:72px;
    font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

/* CONTENT */
.mainstuff
{
    margin-left: 100px;   
}
.mainstuff2
{
   margin-right: 100px; 
}
.maintext
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 150px;  
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.maintext2
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 150px;  
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.contents
{
    margin-bottom: 25px;   
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/* CONTACT US PAGE */
.btn
{
 background-color: grey;
}
.single
{
    width: 60%;
}
.multi
{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
}

/* FOOTER */
.quote
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.quote h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.social
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.social h1
{
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
.social img
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.socialize
{
    padding-top: 30px;   
}
.bottom-nav
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bottom-nav h3
{
    font-size: 20px; 
}
.bottom-nav a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.copyright h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (max-width: 360px)
{
    /* BANNER */
.banner-text
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:50px;
    font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

/* CONTENT */
.mainstuff
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.mainstuff2
{
    width: 100%;
}
.maintext
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
.maintext2
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
.contents
{
    margin-bottom: 25px;   
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/* CONTACT US PAGE */
.btn
{
 background-color: grey;
}
.single
{
    width: 60%;
}
.multi
{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
}

/* FOOTER */
.quote
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.quote h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.social
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.social h1
{
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
.social img
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.socialize
{
    padding-top: 30px;   
}
.bottom-nav
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bottom-nav h3
{
    font-size: 20px; 
}
.bottom-nav a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.copyright h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* Regular Smartphones */
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 480px)
{
    
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* BIGGER PHONES */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)
{
    
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* Regular Tablets */
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1023px)
{
    /*#############*/
    /*NAVIGATION*/
    .nav-link
    {
        font-size: 1.18rem;
    }
    
    
 /*#############*/
 /* HOMEPAGE */
    #homepage
    {
        margin: 10em 0;
    }
 .homepageQuote
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 5rem;
    }
 .homepageQuote strong
    {
        color: aqua;
    }
    .btn-margin button
    {
        margin-top: 2.5em;
        width: 15em;
        height: 3em;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .btn-margin a
    {
        color: white;   
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    /*#############*/
 /* ABOUTPAGE */
    #aboutpage
    {
        margin: 15rem 0 22rem;   
    }
    .about h1
    {
        font-size: 2.7rem;
        color: white;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .about strong
    {
        color: aqua;
    }
    .about img
    {
        height: 70%;
        width: 95%;
        margin-top: 5rem;
        margin-right: 15rem;
    }
    /*#############*/
    /* SERVICESPAGE */
    #servicespage
    {
        margin: 4rem 0;
    }
    .servicesh1 h1
    {
        color: white; 
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .services-rows
    {
        margin: 0.8rem 0;
    }
    .services h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.3rem;
    }
    .services p
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .progress
    {
        height: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        
    }
    .web
    {
        margin-top: 23px;
    }
    .social h1
    {
        font-size: 2.2em;
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .seo
    {
        margin-top: 13px;
    }
    .design
    {
        margin-bottom: 86px;
    }
    .analytics
    {
        margin-bottom: 87px;
    }
    .seo-p
    {
        margin-bottom: 88px;
    }
    .effort
    {
        margin-bottom: 89px;
    }
    /*#############*/
    /* PRICINGPAGE */
    #pricingpage
    {
        margin: 4rem 0;
    }
    .pricingh1 h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .information p
    {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        line-height: 30px;
        color: black;
    }
    #webtype
    {
        height: 4rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    #pages
    {
        height: 4rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    /*#############*/
    /* CONTACTPAGE */
    #contactpage
    {
        margin: 4.3rem 0;
    }
    .contacth1 h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 3.8rem;
    }
    .form-label
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }
    .single
    {
        height: 3.5rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .multi
    {
        height: 11.4rem;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
    }
    .btn
    {
        width: 10rem;
        height: 4rem;
        border-radius: 40px;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
        .contactimg
    {
        width: 600px;
        height: 0px;   
        border-radius: 40px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
    }
    /*#############*/
 /* WEBDESIGNSPAGE */
    
    
    /*#############*/
 /* BUSINESSCARDSPAGE */
    #businesscards
    {
        margin: 5rem 0;   
    }
    .cardh1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 4.2rem;
    }
    .cards img
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5rem 0;
    }
    
    /*#############*/
 /* CLIENTSPAGE */
    
 /*#############*/
 /* FOOTER */
 #footer
 {
  background-color: #25282b;
  height: auto;
        padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
 }
    .mission
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
        
    }
    .objective
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .quote h4
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .navtitle
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .footernav a
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.224rem;
    }
    .social-follow
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.6rem;
    }
    .social-img img
    {
        margin: 0 15px;
        width: 2.2rem;
        height: 2.2rem;
    }
    .footer-copyright h6
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.3rem;
    }
    /* REDIRECT */
    .redirect
    {
        color: #fff;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 4rem auto 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* Large Tablets/Small Computers */
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) and (max-width: 1366px)
{
    
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* Large Tablets/Small Computers */
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px)
{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Wonder Template</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Farsan" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    </head>
    <!-- Beginning of body -->
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- BANNER -->
            <section id="banner">
                <h1 class="banner-text">Wonder</h1>
            </section>
            <!-- NAVIGATION -->
            <section id="navigation">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navB" aria-controls="navB" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navB">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="template.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About the Nebulas</a>
                      </li>
                        <div class="dropdown show">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-left" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            The Stars
                          </a>

                          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Neutron Star</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Red Giants</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">White Dwarfs</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brown Dwarfs</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Worm Holes</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Black Holes</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Our Team</a>
                      </li> 
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
            </section>
            <!-- CONTENT -->
            <section id="content">
                <!-- PUT IMAGES AND SECTIONS OF DIFFERENT GALAXIES AND STARS ALONG WITH INFORMATION -->
                <!-- Milky Way Galaxy -->
                <div class="row contents">
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <figure class="figure mainstuff">
                            <img src="images/image1_milkyway.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="Andromeda Galaxy">
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Milkyway Galaxy provided by: <br> The Guardian</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md maintext">
                        <p>The Milkyway galaxy is a mysterious galaxy, filled with wonders. This galaxy is our home, our planet and solar system just lie in the arm of the galaxy. It is estimated that the Milkyway galaxy has a diameter of 100,000 ~ 180,000 lightyears and an estimation of 100 ~ 400 billion stars. It is highly suspected and likely that at the center of our galaxy, lies a blackhole named  Sagittarius A. If you would like to learn more about our beautiful galaxy, please click <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way">Here</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- M31 Star -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md maintext2">
                        <p>
                            A red giant is a luminous giant star of low or intermediate mass (roughly 0.3–8 solar masses (M☉)) in a late phase of stellar evolution. The outer atmosphere is inflated and tenuous, making the radius large and the surface temperature around 5,000 K (4,700 °C; 8,500 °F) or lower. The appearance of the red giant is from yellow-orange to red, including the spectral types K and M, but also class S stars and most carbon stars. If you would like to learn more about Red Giants, please click <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_giant">Here</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <figure class="figure mainstuff2">
                            <img src="images/image2_redgiant.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="Red Giant">
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Red Giant provided by: <br>The Guardian</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <section id="footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md quote">
                    <h1>There once was a man named Leonard... -Sheldon Cooper</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md social">
                    <h1>Connect With Us!</h1>
                    <div class="row text-center socialize">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <img src="images/icon_facebook.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <img src="images/icon_instagram.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <img src="images/icon_linkedin.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <img src="images/icon_twitter.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md bottom-nav">
                    <h1>Browse our Site:</h1>
                    <h3><a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">About Nebulas</a></h3>
                    <h3><a href="#">The Stars</a> | <a href="#">Worm Holes</a></h3>
                    <h3><a href="#">Black Holes</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact Our Team</a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright">
                <h1>Copyright &copy; 2018; All Rights Reserved</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is in your media queries you havent removed the margins you have set so you would need to do something like this

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    color: white;
}

html,body
{
 height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}
#container
{
 min-height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}
#banner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(images/banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#content
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
 padding-bottom: 240px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 10px;
}
#footer
{
 background-color: #333;
 position: relative;
 height: 240px;
 margin-top: -240px;
 clear: both;
}

/* Conditionals */

/* BANNER */
.banner-text
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:72px;
    font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

/* CONTENT */
.mainstuff
{
    margin-left: 100px;   
}
.mainstuff2
{
   margin-right: 100px; 
}
.maintext
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 150px;  
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.maintext2
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 150px;  
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.contents
{
    margin-bottom: 25px;   
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/* CONTACT US PAGE */
.btn
{
 background-color: grey;
}
.single
{
    width: 60%;
}
.multi
{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
}

/* FOOTER */
.quote
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.quote h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.social
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.social h1
{
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
.social img
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.socialize
{
    padding-top: 30px;   
}
.bottom-nav
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bottom-nav h3
{
    font-size: 20px; 
}
.bottom-nav a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.copyright h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (max-width: 360px)
{
    /* BANNER */
.banner-text
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:50px;
    font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

/* CONTENT */
.mainstuff
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.mainstuff2
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.maintext
{
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    clear: both;
}
.maintext2
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    clear: both;
}
.contents
{
    margin-bottom: 25px;   
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/* CONTACT US PAGE */
.btn
{
 background-color: grey;
}
.single
{
    width: 60%;
}
.multi
{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
}

/* FOOTER */
.quote
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.quote h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.social
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.social h1
{
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
.social img
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.socialize
{
    padding-top: 30px;   
}
.bottom-nav
{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bottom-nav h3
{
    font-size: 20px; 
}
.bottom-nav a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.copyright h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* Regular Smartphones */
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 480px)
{
    
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* BIGGER PHONES */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)
{
    
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* Regular Tablets */
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1023px)
{
    /*#############*/
    /*NAVIGATION*/
    .nav-link
    {
        font-size: 1.18rem;
    }
    
    
 /*#############*/
 /* HOMEPAGE */
    #homepage
    {
        margin: 10em 0;
    }
 .homepageQuote
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 5rem;
    }
 .homepageQuote strong
    {
        color: aqua;
    }
    .btn-margin button
    {
        margin-top: 2.5em;
        width: 15em;
        height: 3em;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .btn-margin a
    {
        color: white;   
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    /*#############*/
 /* ABOUTPAGE */
    #aboutpage
    {
        margin: 15rem 0 22rem;   
    }
    .about h1
    {
        font-size: 2.7rem;
        color: white;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .about strong
    {
        color: aqua;
    }
    .about img
    {
        height: 70%;
        width: 95%;
        margin-top: 5rem;
        margin-right: 15rem;
    }
    /*#############*/
    /* SERVICESPAGE */
    #servicespage
    {
        margin: 4rem 0;
    }
    .servicesh1 h1
    {
        color: white; 
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .services-rows
    {
        margin: 0.8rem 0;
    }
    .services h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.3rem;
    }
    .services p
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .progress
    {
        height: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        
    }
    .web
    {
        margin-top: 23px;
    }
    .social h1
    {
        font-size: 2.2em;
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .seo
    {
        margin-top: 13px;
    }
    .design
    {
        margin-bottom: 86px;
    }
    .analytics
    {
        margin-bottom: 87px;
    }
    .seo-p
    {
        margin-bottom: 88px;
    }
    .effort
    {
        margin-bottom: 89px;
    }
    /*#############*/
    /* PRICINGPAGE */
    #pricingpage
    {
        margin: 4rem 0;
    }
    .pricingh1 h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .information p
    {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        line-height: 30px;
        color: black;
    }
    #webtype
    {
        height: 4rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    #pages
    {
        height: 4rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    /*#############*/
    /* CONTACTPAGE */
    #contactpage
    {
        margin: 4.3rem 0;
    }
    .contacth1 h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 3.8rem;
    }
    .form-label
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }
    .single
    {
        height: 3.5rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .multi
    {
        height: 11.4rem;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
    }
    .btn
    {
        width: 10rem;
        height: 4rem;
        border-radius: 40px;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
        .contactimg
    {
        width: 600px;
        height: 0px;   
        border-radius: 40px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
    }
    /*#############*/
 /* WEBDESIGNSPAGE */
    
    
    /*#############*/
 /* BUSINESSCARDSPAGE */
    #businesscards
    {
        margin: 5rem 0;   
    }
    .cardh1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 4.2rem;
    }
    .cards img
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5rem 0;
    }
    
    /*#############*/
 /* CLIENTSPAGE */
    
 /*#############*/
 /* FOOTER */
 #footer
 {
  background-color: #25282b;
  height: auto;
        padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
 }
    .mission
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
        
    }
    .objective
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .quote h4
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .navtitle
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .footernav a
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.224rem;
    }
    .social-follow
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.6rem;
    }
    .social-img img
    {
        margin: 0 15px;
        width: 2.2rem;
        height: 2.2rem;
    }
    .footer-copyright h6
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.3rem;
    }
    /* REDIRECT */
    .redirect
    {
        color: #fff;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 4rem auto 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* Large Tablets/Small Computers */
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) and (max-width: 1366px)
{
    
}
/*#################################
###################################
###################################
#################################*/
/* Large Tablets/Small Computers */
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px)
{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Wonder Template</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Farsan" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    </head>
    <!-- Beginning of body -->
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- BANNER -->
            <section id="banner">
                <h1 class="banner-text">Wonder</h1>
            </section>
            <!-- NAVIGATION -->
            <section id="navigation">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navB" aria-controls="navB" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navB">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="template.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About the Nebulas</a>
                      </li>
                        <div class="dropdown show">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-left" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            The Stars
                          </a>

                          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Neutron Star</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Red Giants</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">White Dwarfs</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brown Dwarfs</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Worm Holes</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Black Holes</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Our Team</a>
                      </li> 
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
            </section>
            <!-- CONTENT -->
            <section id="content">
                <!-- PUT IMAGES AND SECTIONS OF DIFFERENT GALAXIES AND STARS ALONG WITH INFORMATION -->
                <!-- Milky Way Galaxy -->
                <div class="row contents">
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <figure class="figure mainstuff">
                            <img src="images/image1_milkyway.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="Andromeda Galaxy">
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Milkyway Galaxy provided by: <br> The Guardian</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md maintext">
                        <p>The Milkyway galaxy is a mysterious galaxy, filled with wonders. This galaxy is our home, our planet and solar system just lie in the arm of the galaxy. It is estimated that the Milkyway galaxy has a diameter of 100,000 ~ 180,000 lightyears and an estimation of 100 ~ 400 billion stars. It is highly suspected and likely that at the center of our galaxy, lies a blackhole named  Sagittarius A. If you would like to learn more about our beautiful galaxy, please click <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way">Here</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- M31 Star -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md maintext2">
                        <p>
                            A red giant is a luminous giant star of low or intermediate mass (roughly 0.3–8 solar masses (M☉)) in a late phase of stellar evolution. The outer atmosphere is inflated and tenuous, making the radius large and the surface temperature around 5,000 K (4,700 °C; 8,500 °F) or lower. The appearance of the red giant is from yellow-orange to red, including the spectral types K and M, but also class S stars and most carbon stars. If you would like to learn more about Red Giants, please click <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_giant">Here</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <figure class="figure mainstuff2">
                            <img src="images/image2_redgiant.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="Red Giant">
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Red Giant provided by: <br>The Guardian</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <section id="footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md quote">
                    <h1>There once was a man named Leonard... -Sheldon Cooper</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md social">
                    <h1>Connect With Us!</h1>
                    <div class="row text-center socialize">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <img src="images/icon_facebook.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <img src="images/icon_instagram.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <img src="images/icon_linkedin.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <img src="images/icon_twitter.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md bottom-nav">
                    <h1>Browse our Site:</h1>
                    <h3><a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">About Nebulas</a></h3>
                    <h3><a href="#">The Stars</a> | <a href="#">Worm Holes</a></h3>
                    <h3><a href="#">Black Holes</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact Our Team</a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright">
                <h1>Copyright &copy; 2018; All Rights Reserved</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where/What did you change?

Comment: `/* CONTENT */
.mainstuff
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.mainstuff2
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.maintext
{
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    clear: both;
}
.maintext2
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Farsan', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    clear: both;
}`

Comment: Basically on all your mainstuff and maintexts in the media query I removed the margins you had set

Comment: @Grant remember that if your media queries are at standard bootstrap `sm`, `md`, `lg`, etc breakpoints you can use bootstrap utility classes like `m-lg-0` to fix this issue. More info: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation

Comment: Glad to help! If I helped you solve this issue please mark my answer as correct!